# Distance between probability measures supported in different dimensions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

One can compute the distance between probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ using different types of metrics (when their support lies in the same dimension). For instance, in a finite-dimensional setting, one can measure the distance between two multivariate Gaussian densities $f_1\sim \mathcal{N}^{(k)}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1)$ and $f_0\sim \mathcal{N}^{(l)}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_0,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0)$ as $$d(f_1\vert\vert f_0)=\sqrt{2D_{KL}(f_1\vert\vert f_0)}$$ where, $D_{KL}(\cdot\vert\vert\cdot)$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence and $k,l$ are  the dimensions associated to each density. This only works when $k=l$, because $D_{KL}(\cdot\vert\vert\cdot)$ is not defined otherwise.

Therefore, is there a ''metric'' or an extension of traditional metrics (e.g., Lévy-Prokhorov, total variation, Wasserstein) to compute the ''distance'' (or some kind of similarity indicator) between probability measures/densities that are supported on different dimensions (i.e., for $k\neq l$) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I do not know if it is very natural to ask if there can be a metric between distributions on different dimensions, but check out the concept of distance correlation in the paper "Measuring and testing independence by correlation of distances" by Bakirov, Rizzo and Szekely. This is a measure of dependence between two distributions. See if you can get a metric out of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the paper Landon. However, if the densities are standard Gaussian, the distance covariance/correlation is zero. I guess one can apply some transformation so they can be compared in the same dimension.

Comment: You can do this by embedding everything into an infinite-dimensional space.  Then you can use the Levy-Prokhorov metric on the probability measures on that space.